# Turn off LOAD DATA INFILE or INTO OUTPUT

Tags: mysql, sql, security

As a security minded person, in the off chance that an SQL injection ever happens I'd like to minimize the damage caused. One such possibility is that there are queries that can read and write information to a file on the local file system. This is clearly a major issue in the case of a security breach, and the usage for these commands is fairly limited in day to day usage. Optionally, it could be turned on for an isolated period of time in case I have the need for import and exporting data, but I would like to have it turned off explicitly any other time. No amount of googling or skimming the MySQL manual has led me to a specific setting that allows me to disable this option.

I know I could easily just revoke the privilege for all users, but I'd like a simpler solution that by default increases my security (at least in this specific case).

Does anyone know of any setting or way to deactivate any file interactions in MySQL?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually features like `LOAD DATA INFILE` are disabled by default and have to be enabled in an explicit manner. For example in a configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html says:

> Also, to use `LOAD DATA INFILE` on server files, you must have the `FILE` privilege.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html says:

> The `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'` form of `SELECT` writes the selected rows to a file. The file is created on the server host, so you must have the `FILE` privilege to use this syntax.

You can also set the [secure_file_priv](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) config variable:

> By default, this variable is empty. If set to the name of a directory, it limits the effect of the `LOAD_FILE()` function and the `LOAD DATA` and `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` statements to work only with files in that directory.

In [Percona Server, `secure_file_priv`](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.6/management/secure_file_priv_extended.html) has an additional usage:

> When used with no argument, the `LOAD_FILE()` function will always return NULL. The `LOAD DATA INFILE` and `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` statements will fail with the following error: “The MySQL server is running with the `–secure-file-priv` option so it cannot execute this statement”.